# Shared java resources in XPages applications

Tags: java, xpages

I try to implement most of the logic in any XPages application in Java. I don’t like the idea of attaching the jars or java code in the NSFs. I want to create repositories of java code that is available in all applications on a given server (maven). I know about the Domino/jvm /lib/ext  folder. I also know I can use the JavaUserClassesExt=pathToJava resources in notes.ini
So the question is, are those methods mentioned above the best options to share java resources in an pure XPages environment  or should I consider other alternatives?

Answer (score 3):

You might check out this link, it will show you the basics of creating an "extension library"

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/creating_an_xpages_library#Create+the+library+class

that you can use to implement a java jar across the whole server and replicate using the updatesite template to all your domino servers.

Answer (score 2):

The XPages way to create shared resources for all applications for a given server is to code an OSGi plug-in (a.k.a. extension library). This way you can clearly declare the dependencies of your NSFs, it will survive reinstalls upgrades and when you use the updatesite.nsf approach can be shared between servers too.

There's a book detailing how to build one.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Have you got the title of this book?
I don’t know much about creating OSGI plugins. My first reaction is that ut might be the best option in a released application. But what about the development phase?  I believe it can be very time consuming to create a new version of an OSGI bundle possibly several times in one day. I try to compare this approach to the more ‘old school’ way and standalone simple jar files
By using Eclipse / Maven,  an update will be ready in seconds with a simple maven- install command.

Comment: The title is: "XPages Extension Library: A Step-by-Step Guide to the Next Generation of XPages Components" http://www.amazon.com/XPages-Extension-Library-Step---Step/dp/0132901811

Comment: The Extension Library book is a walkthrough of the key components of the library from IBM, and does not cover how to develop your own. The easiest way to get started developing your own library is to download the XSP Starter Kit from OpenNTF.

Comment: To speed up development of an OSGi plugin in Domino, configure your local Domino server to allow Java debugging, then set up a corresponding debug configuration in Eclipse. This will allow you to see your changes immediately on that server without having to redeploy the plugin with each change. When everything's behaving as desired, then push it to production using the OSGiNSF approach Stephan mentioned.

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting. I will definitely investigate this approach further.
Just out of curiosity, can you explain what is wrong with the lib/ext ( or equivalent notes.ini path setting)  approach?
It would have the great benefit of using the same artifacts in both XPages and back-end java agents